# Using role signature in mixins

Tags: oop, mixins, raku, parameterized-constructor

There seems to be a problem in using the signature given to a role in the roles you want to mix-in. Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

role by-n[$n=1] {
    method multiply(Str $str) { return $str x $n; }
}

role by-string[$n=1] does by-n[$n] {
    method whatever(Str $str) { return $n ~ "→" ~ $.multiply( $str ); }
}

class mighty-þor does by-string[2] {};

say mighty-þor.whatever("*");
```

This returns an error, which seems to indicate `$n` has a `Mu` type:

```
Cannot resolve caller infix:<x>(Str, Mu); none of these signatures match:
    ()
    ($x)
    ($s, Num:D $n)
    ($s, Any:D $n)
    ($s, Any:U $n)
    (Str:D $s, Int:D $repetition --> Str:D)
    (str $s, int $repetition --> str)
  in method multiply at composable-roles-fail.p6 line 4
  in method whatever at composable-roles-fail.p6 line 8
  in block <unit> at composable-roles-fail.p6 line 13
```

However, `role by-string[$n=1] does by-n[1]` or any other number works well. Trying to fix the type in the signature:

```
role by-n[Int $n=1] {
    method multiply(Str $str) { return $str x $n; }
}

role by-string[Int $n=1] does by-n[$n] {
    method whatever(Str $str) { return $n ~ "→" ~ $.multiply( $str ); }
}
```

yields a different error:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/jmerelo/Code/perl6/dev.to-code/perl6/composable-roles-fail.p6
No appropriate parametric role variant available for 'by-n'
at /home/jmerelo/Code/perl6/dev.to-code/perl6/composable-roles-fail.p6:11
```

While, once again, changing it to `role by-string[Int $n=1] does by-n[1]` works. Any idea of what's going on here or what can be done to fix this?

Comment: This feels like a bug.  Anytime a `Mu` is appearing unexpectedly, it usually is.  Will look at this further after having done the Perl 6 Weekly, unless someone beats me to  it :-)

Comment: Want me to file the bug somewhere? Thanks a lot for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My conclusion is that this is a bug, or at least an NYI.

The problem is that the `$n` in `by-string` isn't really set until the role is actually composed into a class.  However, the adding of the role `by-n` happens at compile time of the `by-string` role.  At which time we don't know the value it will get when `by-string` is composed.

So, for this to work, we would need to delay the adding of the `by-n` role to the `by-string` role until the `by-string` role is composed.  And that's not how it's currently implemented, afaics.

I'm pretty sure there is a ticket for this already.  But to be sure this doesn't fall through the cracks, you should maybe open a GitHub issue.

Meanwhile, the only way I see around this at the moment, is to copy the methods of the `by-n` role manually to the `by-string` role.

Wish I had better news for you.

Comment: Coming back here, years later, checking with the latest version of Raku and finding the self same error. Only difference is another multi in the error message: `    (Str:D $s, Bool:D $repetition --> Str:D)`

Comment: @jjmerelo Did you file a bug in the end?

Comment: I checked around, and if I did, it was either closed or worded differently...